# What MacGuffin can convince a "bronzish" age city state with no stakes on a war to go to war

Tags: warfare, economy, politics, bronze-age

First of all, not sure if it's a worldbuilding question but I've read some of the questions here and on RPG stack exchange and my question seemed more fit for this stack exchange. Hope I'm right.

I'm running a role playing campaign set on a fictional world of my creation set in a lowish fantasy late bronze age.
My players don't have any reason to get there but if you are, major spoilers ahead. Stop reading! :-P

Now that we are alone, the explanation of the setting and the question.

In this world there is magic. The source of most of the magic in the world are very powerful and solitary dragons that rule the most powerful city states that occupy the most fertile lands of the world.

The dragons are solitary and territorial beings (in relation to other dragons) that usually create theocracies around them. They teach some humans their magic and the humans that learn that magic are the clergy/public servants/rules of those theocracies.

The dragon and the clergy *do really* make the river grow and prevent plagues to the grain and stuff like that.

Aside from that big slow city building magic there are human magic users that unknowingly tap into the same power as dragons but it's something forbidden in the draconic cities and not as powerful.

That means that the life of most humans is affected by magic in a similar way as it was affected by religion in a similar time period. There is a god-ruler that keeps the city from crumbling and there are witches and sages on the fringes of society that may tell fortunes or place boons and magic is something perceived as real but not an everyday tool (that will be important in a bit, I guess).

The transfer of power between dragons is a bit peculiar. When a dragon dies it always leaves behind an unhatched egg. The clergy take care of the egg for the, usually a couple of years it takes to hatch and then a new dragon is born with all the knowledge of the predecessor.

That has been the way things worked on the home-city of the player characters grandparents for as long as anyone remembers.

But roughly 70 years ago the last dragon died and the egg has not hatched since.
The clergy has kept transferring the knowledge of magic and performing the rituals so the city has not been drowned by the rivers and the crops have kept coming.

But the unrest grew once everyone noticed something was wrong. There was no dragon and the clergy started demanding more and more power by fear of losing it.

With no all powerful dragon on the top of the ziggurat to instill fear and awe some people started fighting the tyranny of the clergy.

40 years ago there was a civil war between the Dragonate and the rebels. The rebels lost and fled south into exile into a confederacy of small city states known as the free cities.

They fled to some not-so-fertile city states that were outside the influence of the dragon even when it was alive but that have thrived with great developments of technology (for the era) and commerce since they have not to worry about the dragon a bit north.

There the exiles formed a community and amassed quite some wealth as traders themselves and they are planning to try to overthrow the Dragonate in their homeland again.
To do so they plan on crossing a big desert south of the free cities in search of a rumored empire that lives without rule of any dragon and recruit their help to march against the Dragonate.

Some of the exiles have liquidated their riches in the free cities, amassed a great deal of supplies and convinced a tribe of nomadic shepherds to man a caravan to try to open a new commercial route south of the desert.

The players are mercenaries/grandchildren of exiles/seekers of fortune in this caravan.

So… What do the exiles carry south to convince this rumored empire to lend soldiers in this war?

I’ve thought of some answers but I don’t like any so far:

- **The spoils of war / land north** The exiles are working to retake their land and free their people. Of course they could offer some to
  the mercenaries that help them but they are not willing to trade one
  master for another.
- **Gold / Tin / Riches**: Gold is used to trade. Tin is great demand to make bronze but hose are not a very compelling MacGuffin. The exiles have
  amassed gold or other riches and they just hire mercenaries? It's not very epic. It could work but it's very mundane.
- **The secret to steel**. There is no steel yet but the world is “ready”
  for it. Maybe it was a secret discovery made in the free cities.
  Maybe there is some magic involved in the process to create it and in
  the bronze age of the world that would be huge… but I don’t see how
  you can “trade” that secret with a nation to which you are already
  asking for help and not be crushed by it. Maybe promise to produce
  steel for them as payment but not give them the secret? That could
  work but it’s risky.

Thanks for reading that far, that was really a lot. At the moment whatever it is their are protecting in the caravan in the trip south is a MacGuffin and if it was a short story that would be great to leave unanswered but at some point some player would open the chest so any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's closed (rightfully so), but you can consider a religious item of those people and that there's more in the city. Otherwise simply the knowledge that there is turmoil and possibly the clergy without power that would make the city easy to capture.

Comment: Wars start for silly reasons... "The ambassador bowed to the Queen first, the Letch! wipe them out to protect our daughters!", or "The ambassador spat out the pomegranate seeds in his hand! He is trying to steal our sacred seeds!", or "The ambassador wiped his butt with his *right* hand, and then later ATE with the same hand. He is a Demon. Wipe them out!!!"...... And these are not fantasy scenarios, but (somewhat parodied) real historical cases.

Comment: I'm sorry i did not find the "off-topic" guide before posting. I did suspect that might be the case. Thanks for the comments and answers.

Answer (score 2):

**Magic knowledge.**

From your OP:  *The clergy has kept transferring the knowledge of magic and performing the rituals so the city has not been drowned by the rivers and the crops have kept coming.*

That is not chump change, that knowledge!  Probably the clergy keeps it to themselves, but any city state could benefit from this kind of thing.  The question is how to prove to these unknown parties that such magic knowledge exists and could be theirs.  Maybe bring some products of the agriculture that the dragon state supports: silk, whiskey, sugar, cinnamon; what have you.

If these southern folks want cinnamon and licorice they are going to have to go up there and capture some clergy and convince them to spread their knowledge.

---

This could very well be a case of careful what you wish for.  The clergy use their magic knowledge to keep a lock on power in their city.  Your people think they will get these outlanders to overthrow the clergy and then your people will be free.  On meeting the outlanders and hearing what they want, the clergy might instead happily go to this other city, using their powers there and so expanding their sphere of influence.  d.

Now the clergy are more powerful!  They might be thankful to your outcast people for making the introduction to their new state.  With the help of the outlanders added to their empire, the clergy will invent new dances for your people to perform as tribute.  Your players will actually have to do the dances in real life, with feeling.

Answer (score 1):

**Because with it they can win**

If the MacGuffin gives them such an advantage that they think they cannot lose, they will go to war.

Just imagine the MacGuffin is a crown that allows the wearer to control an unstoppable indestructible iron golem. Such a golem would allow an army to smash fortifications and crush anything before it. Fleeing is the only choice for the enemy.
[image]
To win, you need to stop the wearer, who is protected by an army and could be hidden anywhere.

Such an advantage could lead a country to war for no other reason than simple opportunistic greed.